# scraping python : existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

im scraping from this website https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx to get kurs price table.it looks like im getting blocked by that website.
[image]
[image]
with selenium and bs4,but when im trying to get the table i got error like this

> ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054,
> 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None,
> 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

and this is my code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.implicitly_wait(10) #secs


# click "usd"

book = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"selectPeriod")))
sel = Select(book)
sel.select_by_value("range")

bookk = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_ddlmatauang1")))
sel = Select(bookk)
sel.select_by_value("USD  ")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

start_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtFrom")
start_date.send_keys("20-Nov-15")
end_date = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_6c89d4ad_107f_437d_bd54_8fda17b556bf_ctl00_txtTo")
end_date.send_keys(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

time.sleep(5)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@value='Cari']")
buttons[1].click()

src = driver.page_source # gets the html source of the page
headers = {
    #"Referer": "https://id.investing.com/commodities/gold-historical-data",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
parser = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml") # initialize the parser and parse the source "src"
url = "https://www.bi.go.id/id/statistik/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/Default.aspx"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = r.text
table = parser.find("table", attrs={"class" : "table1"}) # A list of attributes that you want to check in a tag)
rows = table.find_all('tr')
data = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
    
result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['nilai', 'kurs_jual', 'kurs_beli', 'tanggal'])
result.to_csv("kurs1.csv", index=False)

df = pd.read_csv("kurs1.csv")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)
```

what should i do? please help me,actually a month ago i already succeed but suddenly the class,id from that website changed so i have to change it all.when i try to run it again i got connection error.im stuck since weeks ago! thank you in advance the csv file shouldve been like this
[image]

Comment: are you trying to get 5 years history? I guest the server is timeout processing large data, try with a month or year.

Comment: i still get the same error... :(